# Laravel Join with Where (Case) and AND

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5.4

I'm having problem converting my SQL query to laravel queries. I want to join two tables `users` and `messages` so that i can get the users that has conversation with other users.

Database Structure:

Users:
[image]

Messages:

[image]

This is my SQL query where I get what I want:

[image]

```
SELECT u.id, c.id, u.first_name, u.last_name FROM messages c, users u 
      WHERE (CASE WHEN c.user_one =  @USERID THEN c.user_two = u.ID WHEN c.user_two = @USERID THEN c.user_one= u.id END ) 
      AND ( c.user_one = @USERID OR c.user_two = @USERID ) Order by c.id DESC Limit 20
```

This is my Laravel query:

```
DB::table('messages')
   ->join('users', function($join) use ($user_id) {
        $join->select(DB::raw('CASE WHEN messages.user_one = ' . $user_id . ' THEN messages.user_two = ' . $user_id . 'WHEN messages.user_two = ' . $user_id . ' THEN messages.user_one = ' . $user_id));
        $join->on(function($query) use ($user_id)
        {
             $query->where('messages.user_one', '=', $user_id);
             $query->orWhere('messages.user_two', '=',$user_id);
        });       
   })
   ->select('users.*', 'messages.*')
   ->get();
```

Comment: please add your both database table structure

Comment: I added my db structure. Thanks.

Comment: You can use Raw query in laravel if you have problem with conversion

Comment: messages is a pivot table ?
where message is actually stored ?

Comment: messages is a physicial table. Im just trying to convert my sql query to laravel query. my query is working fine.

Comment: I don't understand your problem. Somebody here might solve your problem. Best of luck

Comment: Okay sir. Thank you.